# La phrase « y pouvoir » est-elle utilisée seulement dans un sens négatif ?

Tags: pronoms, négation, locutions

Sur http://linguee.com/, j'ai trouvé beaucoup d'entrées pour

> je n'y peux rien

qui veut dire que je ne peux rien faire « à » ce dont je parle, mais je n'en ai pas trouvé une seule pour

> j'y peux.

J'ai entendu

> Qu'est-ce que j'y peux ?

dans une chanson, mais je pense que le chanteur veux dire qu'il ne peut rien faire et donc il y a toujours un sens négatif.

Est-ce que l'on peut l'utiliser avec des sens positifs ? Par exemple, une phrase comme celle-ci est-elle possible ?

> Si tu as des problèmes avec des insectes, ce que tu y peux, c'est nettoyer les...

Comment: Je vais y (le) faire. Pas sur que cela soit grammaticalement correct, mais très employé à l'oral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette expression est en effet connotée de manière négative assez souvent et son emploi se ramène principalement à « y pouvoir rien ».

Une utilisation moins négative est celle ci :

> Tu y peux quelque chose !

Malgré tout, cela garde toujours une mauvaise connotation.

**À noter** que l'expression *y pouvoir* n'est que très peu utilisé à l'écrit mais beaucoup plus à l'oral.

D'autres expressions avec *y* sont intéressantes tel que *y faire* qui peut prendre un aspect négatif :

> Je ne peux rien y faire

ou un aspect positif :

> Il sait y faire !

Answer (score 3):

Employé comme locution « Je n'y peux rien » marque l'impuissance ou la non-responsabilité.
Le sens de cette locution est : « Je suis hors d'état de m'opposer à cela, je ne puis l'empêcher ou y remédier, je ne peux rien changer à cela »<sup>1</sup>.

Employée hors contexte c'est ainsi que l'expression est comprise, la présence de la négation « ne ... rien » fait que l'expression ne peut être que négative.

De même que la question :

> Qu'y puis-je ?

est une question la plupart du temps rhétorique qui est un constat d'échec, et qui revient à dire que je n'y peux rien.

Mais le contexte fait tout. Pour employer « y pouvoir » de façon positive il suffit de mettre « quelque chose » à la place de « rien ».

> Souhaitons que cette page d'écriture soit rapidement terminée et nous y pouvons quelque chose ! (F. Mitterrand, *De l'Allemagne, de la France*)
>
> Les baby-boomers, qui deviendront des pappy-boomers, sont très nombreux et ont l'intention de s'emparer de la question de l'âge en démontrant que nous y pouvons quelque chose.   ([NosDéputés.fr](http://www.nosdeputes.fr/14/intervention/564084))
>
> [...] il y a une énorme différence : quand cela vient d'un volcan, nous n'y pouvons rien, c'est pour cela que cela n'amène aucun commentaire, lorsque c'est d'origine anthropique, forcément nous y pouvons quelque chose [...] (Commentaire sur un forum de l'[Expansion](http://energie.lexpansion.com/climat/le-nuage-du-volcan-eyjafjoll-plus-radioactif-que-thernobyl_a-35-4448.html)
>
> Non ! C’est notre affaire à tous et nous y pouvons quelque chose. ([Souffrance et travail](http://www.souffrance-et-travail.com/a-propos/le-site/))
>
> ─ Je n'y peux rien monsieur le maire, et vous non plus ! [...]
> ─  Si, j'y peux quelque chose dit-il.  (*[Un village français](http://books.google.fr/books?id=0vDdQfJEWV4C&pg=PT210&lpg=PT210&dq=%22si%20j%27y%20peux%20quelque%20chose%22&source=bl&ots=JHI_mdWAZF&sig=sgJsW5RJwKORIsyZBEQGD8xj868&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=-er9U8_YIY3taNaXgugG&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22si%20j%27y%20peux%20quelque%20chose%22&f=false)*)

De même pour la question, tout dépend du contexte et du ton : par exemple un ami me raconte ses malheurs, je réagis en lui disant :

> Qu'y puis-je ?

Avec le ton adéquat pour que ce soit perçu, non comme une reconnaissance d'impuissance, mais comme une offre d'aide.

<sub>1. [Le français correct](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Cva6FlQ-5nYC&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=sens+%22je+n%27y+peux+rien+%22&source=bl&ots=9htb5r0HMc&sig=xnA7Hzpm5CaK69VvsHByHcbluwU&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=jN79U9ecHZPkauyyguAF&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=sens%20%22je%20n%27y%20peux%20rien%20%22&f=false)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Il y a quelques entrées dans Google Books dans lesquelles `y pouvoir` est connoté positivemnt. Par exemple pour les plus anciennes

- "Tu y peux musser quelques bandes", Machiavel
- "Tu l'y peux aimer de toute ton âme", Léandre de Dijon

*Lire ces phrases dans un manuscript ancien, même numérisé, est émouvant. Sur http://books.google.fr/, chercher avec `"y peux" -rien -n'y`*

Comment: C'est vrai, mais très ancien et plus du tout utilisé aujourd'hui.